# Creating and indexing a 2D dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is just a quick snippet I made since my code is too complicated to get into, but what I basically want is:

1. A dict with names as keys and an empty list as the value
2. Append to that empty list a list of questions
3. Those questions are keys and their values is an empty list
4. append to that empty list a list of answers

I was able to do this, but my issue is that to reference they question key or assign anything to it, I have to reference its index in that list in addition to the key.

They need to be in lists because each name will have a list of questions, and each question has a list of answers, like so: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAoM0.png)

This code here shows how I'm making my dict and appending to it, in the actual code this is done in loops but this is the jist of it:
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiVg6.png)

Is there a way to get around having to index the list of questions by number? (so I can do what I did above without getting an error)

Update:

I'm starting to realize that this is a blessing since the number index is a quick way to check the question and it's answers. If I index [0] it'll show the the single question and all its answers. Which is helpful since the questions are sentences and typing them could be a pain.

I'm still curious if there's an answer to my question though, so I'll post this anyways.

Code in text:

```
>names = ["john","mark","jake"]
>namesDict = {x:[] for x in names}
>namesDict
{'mark': [], 'jake': [], 'john': []}
>namesDict["mark"].append({"question":[]})
>namesDict
{'mark': [{'question': []}], 'jake': [], 'john': []}
>namesDict["mark"]["question"].append("answer")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
>namesDict["mark"][0]["question"].append("answer")
>namesDict
{'mark': [{'question': ['answer']}], 'jake': [], 'john': []}
```

Comment: Please post your code and all relevant information as *text*, not images!

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Updated. Forgot SO format's the code by coloring it, didn't want to make it too confusing.

Comment: The only way to reference a specific item in a list is by specifying its index, so I don't think there's an answer to your question.

Comment: tbh this question itself is too broad and vague. please make it simple and present your code accordingly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for here is to skip the lists and nest up some dictionaries. It would look something like this:

```
names = ["john","mark","jake"]
namesDict = {x: {} for x in names}

namesDict['mark']['question1'] = []

namesDict['mark']['question1'].extend(('ans1_1', 'ans1_2', 'ans1_3'))
print(namesDict)  # {'john': {}, 'mark': {'question1': ['ans1_1', 'ans1_2', 'ans1_3']}, 'jake': {}}

namesDict['mark']['question2'] = []
namesDict['mark']['question2'].extend(('ans2_1', 'ans2_2', 'ans2_3'))
print(namesDict)  # {'john': {}, 'mark': {'question1': ['ans1_1', 'ans1_2', 'ans1_3'], 'question2': ['ans2_1', 'ans2_2', 'ans2_3']}, 'jake': {}}
```

The only thing holding you back is if `namesDict['mark']` will have multiple values that match to `question1`.