# Dictionary format with dicts in lists in dict

Tags: python

Is something like this even possible??

```
{'SEC': [{'t_name': 'UGA', 't_clubhouse': 'www.uga.com'}],
        [{'t_name': 'BAMA', 't_clubhouse': 'www.bama.com'}],
        [{'t_name': 'VANDY', 't_clubhouse': 'www.vandy.com'}]}
```

I know you have to have unique keys but I'm struggling to understand how to create a dictionary like above since I need everything grouped into a conference.  Here are some generic lists I'm trying to create the dict from:

```
conference = 'SEC'
team_list = ['UGA', 'BAMA', 'VANDY']
team_clubhouse = ['uga.com', 'bama.com', 'vandy.com']
```

I'm wanting to throw all of this into a db but for now, I'd like to create the dict first and then be able to pipe that into Peewee for insertion.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a list of dicts or a tuple of multiple lists, each holding one dict? Also, why not just use a single dict, mapping names to clubhouses (assuming names are unique)?

Comment: @tobias_k I am scapping by conference.  So the script runs and build the lists I need (about 5) for each conference.  Then I need a way to insert all those lists I created into the db but I want to insert them by conference.  I'm sure the way I'm doing it may not be the most efficient way to go about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> team_list = ['UGA', 'BAMA', 'VANDY']
>>> team_clubhouse = ['uga.com', 'bama.com', 'vandy.com']
>>> [{'t_name': team, 't_clubhouse': clubhouse}
     for team, clubhouse in zip(team_list, team_clubhouse)]
[{'t_name': 'UGA', 't_clubhouse': 'uga.com'},
 {'t_name': 'BAMA', 't_clubhouse': 'bama.com'},
 {'t_name': 'VANDY', 't_clubhouse': 'vandy.com'}]
```

Above creates a list of dictionaries.

Map a key `conference` to the list to get the dictionary you want (You can map a key to a value, not multiple values):

```
>>> conference = 'SEC'
>>> {conference: [{'t_name': team, 't_clubhouse': clubhouse}
     for team, clubhouse in zip(team_list, team_clubhouse)]}
{'SEC': [
    {'t_name': 'UGA', 't_clubhouse': 'uga.com'},
    {'t_name': 'BAMA', 't_clubhouse': 'bama.com'},
    {'t_name': 'VANDY', 't_clubhouse': 'vandy.com'}
]}
```

Comment: Good ol'e list comp.  My arch enemy.  I really need to get a better handle on this.  Thanks for this.  I'll try it out.

Comment: While I didn't end up using this method, it did answer the original question that I asked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you need a list here. Just deep nest some dicts.

```
NCAA = {'SEC': {'team1': {'nickname': 'UGA', 'clubhouse': 'uga.com'}},
               {'team2': {'nickname': 'BAMA', 'clubhouse': 'bama.com'}},
               {'team3': {'nickname': 'VANDY', 'clubhouse': 'vandy.com'}},
         'Big_10': {'Purdue': {'nickname': 'Boilers', 'clubhouse': 'boiler_up.com'}}}
```

I think that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43685342/creating-and-indexing-a-2d-dictionary/43686174#43686174) is similar and can provide a little more info

Comment: This is a good idea.  I hadn't thought about using just dicts.